# Coin flipping, decision processes and value of information

Tags: bayesian, decision-theory

Imagine the following setup: You have 2 coins, coin A which is *guaranteed* to be fair, and coin B which may or may not be fair. You are asked to do 100 coin flips, and your objective is to *maximize the number of heads*.

Your prior information about coin B is that it was flipped 3 times and yielded 1 head. If your decision rule was simply based on comparing the expected probability of heads of the 2 coins, you would flip coin A 100 times and be done with it. This is true even when using reasonable Bayesian estimations (posterior means) of the probabilities, since you have no reason to believe that coin B yields more heads.

However, what if coin B is actually biased in favor of heads? Surely the "potential heads" you give up by flipping coin B a couple of times (and therefore gaining information about its statistical properties) would be valuable in some sense and therefore would factor into your decision. How can this "value of information" be described mathematically?

**Question:** How do you construct an optimal decision rule mathematically in this scenario?

Comment: I'm deleting my answer. Too many people are complaining that I explicitly used a prior (which is standard in the literature). Enjoy Cam Davidson Pilon's incorrect answer where he also assumes a prior (but no one objects) and claims as optimal a method which is 1.035 below optimal.

Comment: whoah, when did this all happen?  BTW, I would agree with Douglas that using a prior is fine. I retract my optimality assertion, as well.

Comment: I'm accepting Cam's solution because it helped me a lot. I agree that it's not optimal, but unless somebody can point out a *general* optimal solution which can easily be computed, it's the best bet.

Comment: Why was it so bad that I used a prior (which I clearly stated) to answer a question tagged "bayesian?"

Comment: I didn't criticize the use of a prior. I mentioned as a sidenote that there might be more appropriate priors than the uniform one (e.g. Jeffrey's), but this is only marginally relevant to the question. Your solution was perfectly fine, just not as useful to me since it doesn't generalize easily.

Comment: It generalizes easily and very widely. And it was correct, unlike the one you accepted. Ok, I'm done with this. Go ahead and use a bad heuristic and call it optimal.

Comment: @DouglasZare I hope you're ok, brother.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Multi-armed Bandit

This is a particular case of a [Multi-Armed bandit problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit). I say a particular case because generally we don't know *any* of the probabilities of heads (in this case we know one of the coins has probability 0.5).

The issue you raise is known as the *exploration vs exploitation* dilemma: do you explore the other options, or do you stick with what you *think* is the best. There is an immediate optimal solution *assuming you knew all probabilities*: simply choose the coin with the highest probability of winning. The problem, as you have alluded to, is that we are unsure about what the *true probabilities* are.

There is lots of literature on the subject, and there are many deterministic algorithms, but since you tagged this Bayesian, I'd like to tell you about my personal favourite solution: *the Bayesian Bandit*!

### The Baysian Bandit Solution

The Bayesian approach to this problem is very natural. We are interested in answering "What is the *probability* that coin X is the better of the two?".

*A priori*, assuming we have observed *no* coin flips yet, we have no idea what the probability of coin B's Heads might be, denote this unknown $p_B$. So we should assign a prior uniform distribution to this unknown probability. Alternatively, our prior (and posterior) for coin A is trivially concentrated entirely at 1/2.

As you have stated, we observe 2 tails and 1 heads from coin B, we need to update our posterior distribution. Assuming a uniform prior, and flips are Bernoulli coin-flips, our posterior is a $Beta( 1 + 1, 1 + 2)$.  Comparing the posterior distributions or A and B now:

[image]

#### Finding an approximately optimal strategy

Now that we have the posteriors, what to do? We are interested in answering "What is the probability coin B is the better of the two" (Remember from our Bayesian perspective, although there is a definite answer to which one is better, we can only speak in probabilities):

$$w_B = P( p_b > 0.5 )$$

The approximately optimal solution is to choose B with probability $w_B$ and A with probability $1 - w_B$. This scheme maximizes out expected gains. $w_B$ can be computed in calculated numerically, as we know the posterior distribution, but an interesting way is the following:

```
1. Sample P_B from the posterior of coin B
2. If P_B > 0.5, choose coin B, else choose coin A.
```

This scheme is also self-updating. When we observe the outcome of choosing coin B, we update our posterior with this new information, and select again. This way, if coin B is really bad we will choose it less, and it  coin B is in fact really good, we will choose it more often. Of course, we are Bayesians, hence we can never be absolutely sure coin B is better. Choosing probabilistically like this is the most natural **solution** to the exploration-exploitation dilemma.

This is a particular example of [Thompson Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_sampling). More information, and cool applications to online advertising, can be found in [Google's research paper](http://www.economics.uci.edu/%7Eivan/asmb.874.pdf) and [Yahoo's research paper](http://explo.cs.ucl.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/An-Empirical-Evaluation-of-Thompson-Sampling-Chapelle-Li-2011.pdf). I love this stuff!

Comment: I don't think that strategy is correct. I don't think you should be choosing whether to pick A or B probabilistically.

Comment: Yes, this is shown to maximize the *expected reward *. See [this google paper](http://www.economics.uci.edu/~ivan/asmb.874.pdf)

Comment: I don't think that paper says what you think it does. If you disagree, please compute the expected number of heads you will obtain under that strategy.

Comment: "Randomized probability matching allocates observation $t+1$ to arm $a$ with probability $w_{at}$" ... "The optimality probabilities in Equation (5) do not need to be computed explicitly. It will usually be faster to simulate $a \sim w_{at} $ by simulating a single draw of [$p_B$] from [$P( p_B | y$] and setting [$a = \arg \max (p_B, 1/2)$]". Please explain where my method diverges.

Comment: Very interesting. Is it possible that this solution is not necessarily optimal but asymptotically optimal in certain environments? (Which ones?) In this case it would seem that the simplicity of this approach makes it very attractive.

Comment: It's optimal almost always, not just asymptotically. (Asymptotically, all methods should agree as we have strong knowledge about what the *best* coin is). The problem is most difficult in the early stages, where we have little information. This method is optimal in this environment *on average*, but *on average* is the best you can do.

Comment: I don't think this is close to optimal. It suggests that on the first flip, you chose B with probability 1/2. It should be clear that you get no information if you choose A, so you should choose B all of the time. The amount you lose by this error is about 0.12 when you make it, so it costs you about 0.06 on the first step. You lose a similar amount when you roughly flip a coin to decide whether to collect any information on the next few steps. Flipping A early means you have less time to exploit an advantage you might find.

Comment: Another way to see that this probabilistic method is not optimal is to consider the last flip. You should not sample from the distribution for B to decide whether to flip B on the last toss, you should compare the mean value with $0.5$.

Comment: @DouglasZare If your only measure is the expected number of heads, given our coin flips, then the best strategy is to always pick coin A. But this is incomplete as it focuses too much on the *explioitation*, and not enough on the potential upside of *exploration*. The logical conclusion of your suggestion is, if we restart the experiment, to flip coin B once: if it is Tails, always choose A; else flip it again, if it is Heads always choose B.

Comment: By asymptotically, what I meant was that this decision rule might closely approximate the true optimal decision rule in many realistic environments, which would be good enough for most cases. My intuition says that Thompson sampling cannot be truly optimal, because there is a (very small) possibility that it will lead to the decision of never flipping coin B, which would clearly not be the optimal decision. Eliminating this option would improve the decision rule, therefore it could not have been optimal before the adjustment. Does this make sense?

Comment: The question said, "your objective is to maximize the number of heads." That is what I am doing, and it is not to flip B only once and then decide permanently whether to choose B. As I stated, the optimal strategy is to give up on B after $0$ heads and $3$ tails, or $1$ head and $5$ tails, etc.

Comment: By contrast, under what criterion is your strategy of flipping A half of the time on the first toss correct?

Comment: @M.Cypher: Why would the there ever be a possibility of not choosing coin B? If coin B is indeed better, the chances are *very* small of never choosing coin B in multiple trials. On the other hand, again if  B is better, there is a chance that you consistently choose B and do great! So, on average you perform optimally.

Comment: @DouglasZare By assuming a uniform prior on coin B, it is fair to say we should choose coin A half the time. I see nothing wrong with that. And to maximize the number of heads, on average, one should follow Thompson Sampling.

Comment: The papers you cite do not state that your strategy is the optimal strategy. This is one reason it is called a heuristic or baseline from which to measure improvements. Thompson sampling is not a good or optimal strategy, it is just asymptotically not bad.

Comment: @Cam: Just because there's a difference between "extremely unlikely" and "impossible". I think it's fair to say that Thompson sampling is a decision rule where the most likely decision is the optimal one. This makes it inferior to any deterministic decision rule which *always* makes an optimal decision.

Comment: If you think it's right to flip A half of the time on the first toss, then your intuition is quite wrong. This is a common error to make, by the way. It comes from using a heuristic which works in Nash equilibrium out of context to probabilistic situations where pure strategies are right.

Comment: Here is a much simpler example: Instead of $100$ tosses, suppose there are only $2$. Thompson sampling gets $49/48 = 1.02$ heads on average, whereas the optimal is $13/12=1.08$. Thompson sampling is not optimal.

Comment: @M.Cypher I understand but I still agree with my methodology: this is a probabilistic situation: we have to understand that with only 3 tosses, inference (including "expected values") is going to be wildly off. My method incorporates this uncertainty. (Just look at the posterior of coin B, it is barely biased towards 0, there is still an enormous chance of it being the better coin).

Comment: @DouglasZare I'm afraid I do not understand this last example. Where are these values from?

Comment: Plus, please share some info about this Nash eq., I'm interested in it's application.

Comment: You want me to explain the Nash equilibrium analogy, which I said is not the right method to use, but it explains where your intuition would be correct instead of wrong, as it is here? Ok. Suppose we play a game. There is a nickel and a dollar on the table. If we choose the same one, you get it. The Nash equilibrium is for you to choose the dollar with probability $1/20$, and the nickel with probability $20/21$, while I also do this. This way we are both indifferent to adjusting the probability. In the Nash equilibrium, there is no right answer or wrong answer...

Comment: but the Nash equilibrium strategy is for you to pick the objects with the probabilities that they pay off, when I play the Nash equilibrium strategy. Sometimes, in zero sum games, you can figure out how you might want to respond based on what your opponent is doing, even if you don't know the payoffs. However, this question is different. This is not a zero sum game with an adversary acting against you. You don't need to avoid being predictable, you should simply make the right play. The right play on the first move is B, exploring, and playing A half of the time is wrong and a costly mistake.

Comment: Similarly, in a game like backgammon, if play X wins $20\%$ and play Y wins $10\%$, you don't split up your plays and sometimes play X and sometimes play Y and call that optimal. You should make the strong move $100\%$ of the time. This should be really clear if you work through the example with only $2$ tosses instead of $100$. Then you should be able to compute everything explicitly. Note that under Thompson sampling, after you observe $1$ head and $0$ tails from B with a uniform prior, you pick B with probability only $3/4$, and after a tail, no head, you pick B with probability $1/4$.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am unnecessarily extending the discussion. I believe I see your point now. Perhaps the scheme falls down because we know coin A's probability. Though I am not convinced my method is inferior *on average*, in this case it appears it is so. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Though, I do not like your backgammon example only because it assumes we know 20% and 10% with certainity. That is not the case here (at least for one of the coins), hence my desire to be probabilistic.

Comment: No, the same happens if A is not known to be a fair coin. You can quantify the value of sampling A versus sampling B (taking into account future uses of the information, as in the Equity function I computed with Mathematica). If sampling A is worth more, the right play is to choose A $100\%$ of the time. The only time it might be ok to use a mixed strategy is when the value of sampling A is equal to the value of sampling B, such as in a symmetric start, but even then you could avoid mixed strategies by breaking all ties in the favor of A.

Comment: The backgammon example shows the important feature whether you want to accept it or not. Mixed strategies are not optimal in problems like this. If you don't believe me, work out the equities in simple examples as I said above. Do it for the case of $2$ tosses. Even though we don't know the probability for B (and we still wouldn't even with $1000$ tosses) there is still a numerical equity for choosing B, and a numerical equity for choosing A, and when the equity for A is higher than the equity for B you should not choose B at all. Thompson sampling is not a a good strategy here.

Answer (score 11):

This is a simple case of a [multi-armed bandit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) problem. As you note, you want to balance the information you collect by trying the unknown coin when you think is suboptimal in the short run against exploiting the knowledge you have.

In the classical multi-armed bandit problem, you would not be certain of the probability for either coin. However, here you are given that you know the value of coin A, so when you flip A, you get no information. In fact, you might as well ignore the stochastic nature of A, and assume you get a flat $1/2$ per choice of A. This means if it is ever right to flip coin A, then you should keep flipping A. So, you just want to find the [optimal stopping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_stopping) rule for when you should give up on B. This depends on the prior distribution for the parameter for B and the number of trials. With a greater number of trials, exploring has more value, so you would test B more.

In general, I think you can't get away from a dynamic programming problem, although there might be special cases where the optimal strategy can be found and checked more simply.

With a uniform prior, here is where you should stop:

$(0 ~ \text{heads}, 3 ~\text{tails}), (1 ~\text{head}, 5 ~\text{tails}), (2 ~\text{heads}, 6 ~\text{tails}), (3,7), (4,8),...(31,35), (32,35), (33,36), (34,37), ... (41,44), (42,44), ... (46,48), (47,48), (48,49), (49,50)$.

Under this strategy, you expect to collect $61.3299$ heads.

I used the following Mathematica code to compute the equities:

```
Clear[Equity];
Equity[n_, heads_, tails_] := Equity[n, heads, tails] = 
    If[n == 0, heads, 
       Max[1/2 + Equity[n - 1, heads, tails], 
           (heads + 1)/(heads + tails + 2) Equity[n - 1, heads + 1, tails] + 
           (tails + 1)/(heads + tails + 2) Equity[n - 1, heads, tails + 1]
           ]
      ]
```

---

For comparison, the Thompson sampling heuristic (which Cam Davidson Pilon claimed is optimal) gives an average of 60.2907 heads, lower by 1.03915. Thompson sampling has the problem that it sometimes samples B when you have enough information to know that it is not a good bet, and it often wastes chances to sample B early, when information is worth the most. In this type of problem, you are almost never indifferent between your options, and there is a pure optimal strategy.

```
tp[heads_, tails_] := tp[heads, tails] = 
    Integrate[x^heads (1 - x)^tails / Beta[heads + 1, tails + 1], {x, 0, 1/2}]


Clear[Thompson];
Thompson[flipsLeft_, heads_, tails_] := Thompson[flipsLeft, heads, tails] = 
    If[flipsLeft == 0, heads, 
       Module[{p = tp[heads, tails]}, 
           p (1/2 + Thompson[flipsLeft-1,heads,tails]) + 
           (1-p)((heads+1)/(heads+tails+2)Thompson[flipsLeft-1,heads+1,tails] + 
           ((tails+1)/(heads+tails+2)) Thompson[flipsLeft-1,heads,tails+1])]]
```

Comment: I agree that an optimal solution would be better than an approximate one. I wonder if there is an optimal *general* solution which can be efficiently applied within milliseconds in a dynamic environment with several hundred "coins". If not, I guess Thompson sampling is the best option.

Comment: Thompson sampling is a poor approximation. There are better approximations you can use if you don't want to go through the trouble of the (at worst quadratic) exact calculation, but still want to avoid large errors. Actually, the exact calculation might be closer to linear.

Comment: What permits us to assume there is a prior *distribution* on B? I admit that such an assumption makes the problem more tractable, but the existence of an *objectively* valid assessment of the fairness of B is doubtful to me. Yes, we do have the results of some previous flips, but those are still consistent with any value for $\Pr_B(\text{heads})$ in $(0,1)$. If in fact that probability is less than $1/2$, then I don't care *what* prior *you* choose to adopt: it will be an objective fact that the expected number of heads with your approach is less than $50$.

Comment: I don't know Mathematica so I can't follow how you computed your expected number of heads. Care to explain that part? If we assume knowledge that coin B's bias is drawn from a uniform distribution on [0,1], then I don't see how you can expect to beat 50/50.

Comment: @whuber: Do you think I made a mistake in assuming there might be a prior distribution, and stating which prior I was using? The same "mistake" seems to be made by every paper I can find on the subject. Without a prior, I'm not sure how you can optimize anything.

Comment: @jerad: It's just dynamic programming with memoization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization. I computed the expected number of heads from the best strategy (the equity) as the maximum over the expected number of heads over each possible option at the step.

Comment: @whuber: Also, why not make the same objection to Cam Davidson Pilon's answer? It seems people like that one better even though it's clearly wrong, so I feel like deleting this one.

Comment: @Douglas: I'm wondering, is there a reason you used the uniform prior and not Jeffrey's prior?

Comment: @M. Cypher: The uniform prior seemed simplest. What's the advantage to using a Jeffreys prior?  As I stated before, the same technique works for other priors, too.

Comment: Douglas: Because I paid more attention to your answer :-).  Please don't get me wrong--I like it and I like this thread. I thought it important to point out that you had to add an assumption in order to obtain your answer, that's all.  As a practical matter, in many situations--including this one--*there is no prior*.  (I sure wouldn't want to make up a personal prior and then have to bet big money on it!)  But of course there is still an optimum, *provided you specify a loss function.*  ("Maximizing" an expectation is not a full loss function.)